# Prevent automatic URL rewrites created that include category URL key in product URL

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, url-rewrite, url-key

Whenever I create a new product, Magento automatically creates unnecessary URL rewrites that include each category and subcategory combination, that use the categories' URL keys in the product path. For example, for a product `product-name` with the categories:

`category
category > subcategory
category > subcategory > third`

...Magento will automatically create URL rewrites with the following request paths:

`/category/product-name
/category/subcategory/product-name
/category/subcategory/third/product-name`

...as well as also creating the in-use URL rewrite with request path:

`/product-name`

**My question is, even though I have the setting `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` set to `No` in:**

**`System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations`**

**...how do I stop these additional URL rewrites from being created automatically?**

Now, again, I realize that the site isn't linking to these additional paths anywhere on the site, but if for some reason a search engine picked up:

`http://example.com/category/subcategory/third/product-name`

...this would load! I'm nervous this will result in duplicate content being indexed by search engines. Since the `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` setting is set to `No`, and all links to the product on the site are pointing to:

`http://example.com/product-name`

...I want to stop Magento from creating these unnecessary URL rewrites automatically.

For reference, I tried truncating the `core_url_rewrite` table to zero (basically emptying it out) and reindexing the Catalog URL Rewrites in `System > Index Management`. This still results in Magento automatically creating these unnecessary URL rewrites.

Also, for reference, I am using Magento Community 1.9.1.

Please advise! Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually looking for a similar solution as I have more than 1.5 millions URL rewrites created for 35 000+ products. All of this caused by categories, subcategories but also many store views.

I just found a **FREE** extension that seems to work on every Magento version (confirmed up to 1.8.1 from the comments)

I'm using the latest 1.9.1 so I will have to test it out but this extension is preventing creation of all subcategories URLs, invisible and disabled products for which Magento also creates URL rewrites for.

**Correction:** From the comments on Magento Connect it works fine on version 1.9.1.

**Please follow this link, all the details are explained in details:**

http://www.dnd.fr/2012/09/magento-patch-how-to-optimize-re-index-processing-time-for-url-rewrite/

**EDIT:** Github Download: https://github.com/molotovbliss/DnD_Magento_Patch_Index_URL

Comment: I have this extension and it works alright, but I noticed today that if I create a new category and put products in it it still creates the rewrites for the products, but if I truncate the rewrite table and rebuild all rewrites it doesn't.  Is this something anyone else has experienced?

Comment: Github download: https://github.com/molotovbliss/DnD_Magento_Patch_Index_URL